# Is that possible to run a script after Maven reads projects and before life cycle starts

Tags: maven

I want to generate a Manifest file for a osgi bundle before Maven reads my project, is that possible by some hooks?

Comment: you could do something in the validate phase, no?

Comment: You should check felix-bundle-plugin which can create a OSGi MANIFEST.MF

Comment: I'm using tycho to build my bundle, I would like to generate my Manifest file firstly. But tycho will read the manifest file after reading the projects in the lifecycle extention in the afterProjectsRead method https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/blob/master/tycho-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/tycho/core/maven/TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java

Answer (score 0):

You can create that MANIFEST with some template tool with another Bundle that starts before yours.

Use `setStartLevel(int startlevel)` (Doc [here](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/startlevel/BundleStartLevel.html)) to set order of start.